# xcode twitter puts up an Error 0x72613c21

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-0x72613c21/54532

This is a link to my post on the twitter community, but it seems that they were unable to fix my issue. For now I've had to comment out the twitter code.

Essentially the issue is that I can run the app simulated or on my iphone, but when i go to export it to put it on test flight xcode throws up an error and wont let me continue

Here is my app delegate code

import UIKit
import CoreData
import Fabric
import TwitterKit
import Parse
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.






    // [Optional] Power your app with Local Datastore. For more info, go to
    // https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore/iOS
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.setApplicationId("v8B41QDdT7Abdf4CIXr5xNtnNffYOJ1AlEW5FeED",
        clientKey: "fc4oICirIO2n7Or9co84DVw4NOVlMeV3D7shlKun")

    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)



    Fabric.with([Twitter.self()])

    return true
}
```

And on the view that has the login on it

```
import UIKit
import TwitterKit


class PhotographerLoginViewController: UIViewController,  
UITextFieldDelegate {







override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
        if let unwrappedSession = session {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logged In",
                message: "User \(unwrappedSession.userName) has logged in",
                preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
            )
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            NSLog("Login error: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }



    }

    // TODO: Change where the log in button is positioned in your view
    logInButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 47, y: 525)
    self.view.addSubview(logInButton)
```

Comment: `0x72613c21` is a memory address, not an error. The error you describe in [your off-site post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-0x72613c21/54532) seems related to [this discussion](https://github.com/AdaptiveMe/adaptive-arp-darwin/issues/52), which suggests raising your minimum deployment target to iOS 8. But you need to add way more detail to your question (enough to help someone reproduce it from scratch) before I can really say what's happening.

Comment: @AaronBrager What kind of detail would you like? i honestly don't know where the issue is so i don't know where to start.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - this covers what you should include in a question